# Please explain the meaning of Kiali's metrics? e.g. mops, mB - see below image & kiali is installed as part of Istio v1.1.1

Tags: istio, kiali

I don't understand the meaning of Kiali's metrics page. The path: Kiali welcome page->workloads->pick one service->click "inbound metrics".

I don't think the red-box marked 'mops' is million op per Second. the below two marked as red 'mB' is 1000-Bytes?

[image: The kiali metrics page]

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

Kiali UI uses a component to automate scales the Y-Axis with the metrics.
Code can be seen here:
https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui/blob/master/src/components/Metrics/MetricsChartBase.tsx#L78

Basically what you are seeing is some units are automatically calculated in the way:
1B = one byte
900 mB = 900 mili-bytes (that's a synthetic metric).

Obviously there are units that are not continuous like bytes and it doesn't make sense more than to show the scale relative.

Which version are you running, last one based on 0.17 ?

I hope this helps.